# Read Json file but keys do not have quotation marks

Tags: java, json, parsing

I wrote following code to read a file

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
```

but it got error when file content is like following

```
{
 needed:"something",
 other1:true,
 other2:"not important"
}
```

error message`Unexpected character (n) at position 1.`

How could I correct it? Thanks

Comment: The file you have isn't JSON. You _might_ be able to do something like treat it as JavaScript and run it through a JS engine, but fixing the broken input is the Correct Approach.

Comment: Easiest thing would be to get the JSON format corrected externally and use current approach to read the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution Jackson library for reading unquoted fields.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
String value = "{" +
     " needed:\"something\"," +
     " other1:true," +
     " other2:\"not important\"" +
     "}";
Map items = objectMapper.readValue(value,  HashMap.class);
System.out.println("Got object " + items);
```

You can pass the file directly to readValue method.

```
Map items = objectMapper.readValue(new File(filePath),  HashMap.class);
```

Instead of HashMap, you can specify your own concrete class also.

```
ConcreteClass items = objectMapper.readValue(new File(filePath),  ConcreteClass.class);
```

Here is the maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```